# Autocomplete for PyroCMS in NetBeans IDE

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, autocomplete, pyrocms

I have done autocomplete for Codeigniter framework in NetBeans IDE by creating a file in nbproject folder something like this...

```
<?
/**
* @property CI_Loader $load
* @property CI_Form_validation $form_validation
* @property CI_Input $input
* @property CI_Email $email
* @property CI_DB_active_record $db
* @property CI_DB_forge $dbforge
* @property CI_Table $table
* @property CI_Session $session
* @property CI_FTP $ftp
* ....
*/
Class Controller {
}
?>
```

But now i am using PyroCMS is there anyway that i can also use autocomplete for PyroCMS in NetBeans IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File` > `Project Properties` : Choose `PHP Include Path` and then `Add Folder` to add the appropriate folder containing the `system` folder.

[image]

Comment: where do i need to copy autocomplete file?